# Convert DataBase objcct into json

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to convert database object into json object using dataweave 1.0

Data base result set.

```
[{
Name : "Ram",
Id : 1,
Dept : "HR"
},
{
Name : "Shyam",
Id : 2,
Dept : "HR"
}]
```

Expected Result:

```
{
Dept: "HR",
  Result:
[{
  Name : "Ram",
  Id : 1 
  },
  {
   Name : "Shyam",
   Id : 2
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your DB object is a typical List of Maps:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

%function extractDept(arr)
  arr[0].Dept default ""
---
{
  Dept:   extractDept(payload),
  Result: payload map {
    Name: $.Name,
    Id:   $.Id
  }
}
```

You can replace the var assignment with any logic you would choose to use in your scenario. Really just depends on the use case.

Comment: Hi jerney, no hr is part of the database object only. Its not a part of the flow variable. How can we do without assigning value to variable( without using variable)

Comment: You'd need to extract it from the payload somehow. There are plenty of ways to do that, depending on your use case. Just swap out the logic for the `extractDept` method with what you need.